# Laravel cookie unexpected output i.e. encrypted result on service provider

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am developing a package where I am registering ServiceProvider and inside my class methods I am saving cookie data as this

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('my_name', 'manash', 120));
```

and I am retrieving like this

```
Cookie::get('my_name')
```

but I am not getting the value as I have stored, instead it is outputting me this value

```
eyJpdiI6InlcL3VxNklrejlKemxLQ012T0pcL3U1QT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJpbzRmajVEUU90YkhhdTdpeFNlcURBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI1MTFiMTk5YjY3ZTczMzI2Nzc1MGI1Mzk3NmU1MjJhYjE3MWRhYWE2OGQ4NWE1Y2Y2NDgyZWQ1YmYxOGQ4OWU1In0=
```

I think it encrypted, but as per my knowledge it should be automatically decrypted when we use get method.
I am using `laravel 5.3.28`

Answer (score -1):

What happens is that all cookies created by laravel are encrypted and signed with an authentication code.
Have you tried with the request?
Like this:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request

Request $request;
$request->cookie('my_name');
```

Comment: I know it is encrypted using the middleware that resides in web middleware group, but as I am saying I want it to resolve within a serviceProvider not in Normal request

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if your middleware is not triggering before Encrypt Cookie middleware
2. Try https://laravel.com/docs/master/encryption see if it works

Comment: there is no middleware as I have already said It is specified in my class which gets registered via ServiceProvider